# Rota padrão controller/action e links para css/js não funcionam cakephp

Tags: php, apache, cakephp-2

Após extrair o cake 2.5.2 para o diretório (Linux) `/var/www/html/teste` ao acessar a url `http://localhost/teste` o mesmo carrega o conteúdo corretamente do controller `pages` e action `display` conforme do arquivo `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

Porém ao tentar acessar o controller diretamente pela url :

`http://localhost/teste/pages/display` tenho o retorno 404 de Page not found.

Fora isso(rs), os arquivos de `css/js/img` da pasta webroot(não estão sendo incluídos pela url gerada) não são carregados.

Url gerada que retorna arquivo não encontrado:

```
http://localhost/teste/css/cake.generic.css
```

Url para acessar o arquivo corretamente:

```
http://localhost/teste/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css
```

A minha solução para os arquivos de css/js/img foi a seguinte, alterei a forma de chamar o arquivo.

Forma utilizada padrão:

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
```

Nova forma:

```
echo $this->Html->css('/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css');
```

Resumindo, penso que talvez o erro realmente seja no apache ou algo parecido, mas não sei exatamente como posso validar essa parte.

A minha solução para o css/js/img, será que está correta? Pois penso que era para funcionar como o exemplo que baixei na versão do cake corretamente.

Caso precisem de mais informações é só falar, valeu.

Comment: Alessandro, o método display não pode ser chamado, ele é um "subcontroller" ele não renderiza nada, só direciona para a view correta.

Answer (score 1):

Precisa chamar as views do `PagesController` desta forma:

```
http://localhost/teste/pages/home
```

O método `display` não retorna view, você requisita direto na url a view que você quer exibir, após o controller `/pages/sua_view`.

Quanto ao css/js/img, normalmente é só chamar assim:

```
echo $this->Html->css(array('forms', 'tables', 'menu'));
```

Will output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/forms.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/tables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/menu.css" />
```

Se isto não está ocorrendo, pode ser que seu servidor não esteja devidamente configurado para utilizar o cake.

Dá uma olhada aqui:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Comment: Então cara, tentei como você disse, ate alterei minha action para index e o nome da view também.. mas sempre da 404, já sobre o css, ele cria certinho o link igual vc disse, mas ele nao encontra o arquivo, ele só encontra pela url `http://localhost/teste/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css` inserindo antes a pasta app/webroot, acha que pode ser algo no .htaccess?

Comment: Você configurou o servidor conforme o site informa? Verifica se gerou os arquivos .htaccess, pode ser sim, um deles é responsável exatamente por direcionar estas requisições para a pasta webroot.

Comment: Só não entendi uma coisa, o PagesController é para páginas estáticas, sem métodos(actions), se você criar métodos, só vai ser acessível pelo controller que você criar.

Comment: Estou dando uma olhada no link cara, pode ser que a solução do meu problema realmente esteja aqui hehe, sobre o controller eu usei esse como exemplo pois já veio com o projeto, mas eu criei outro com o nome do meu objeto extendendo do AppController e mesmo assim não consigo acessar controller/action

Comment: É porque não está devidamente configurado, o .htaccess é fundamental, sem ele nada mais rola..